# Duda con Hilos y con el metodo Scheduled

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente programa:

Clase `Empresa`:

```
public class Empresa {

    List<Treballador> plantilla = new ArrayList();
    public Empresa() {
        plantilla.add(new Treballador("Albert"));
        plantilla.add(new Treballador("Joan"));
        plantilla.add(new Treballador("Maria"));
    }
    public void mostrarTemps() {
        for (Treballador t : plantilla) {
            System.out.println(t.getNom() + " ha treballat " + t.getTemps() + " segons");
        }
    }
}
```

Clase `Treballador`:

```
package ioc.dam.m9.uf2.eac1.Ex1;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Random;

public class Treballador {
    //Nom del treballador
    private String nom;   
    //Ens indica si el treballador està  disponible o no
    private boolean lliure=true;
    //Ens guardarÃ  el "temps" aleatori que li toca treballar
    private int durada=1;
    //Ens ajuda a controlar el "temps" que està  treballant
    private int volta=0;    
    //temps que porta treballat
    private int temps=0;
    //temps que porta treballat
    private long auxTempsIni=0;

    private Calendar cal ;

    public Treballador(String nom) {

        this.nom = nom;   
    }  
    /**
     * Se pone a trabajr. Calculamos la duracion (nombre de vueltas) aleatoras
     */  
    public void treballa() {
        setLliure(false);
        Random r =new Random();
        durada = r.nextInt(20)+5;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public boolean isLliure() {
        boolean ret = lliure;
        incrementa();
        return ret;
    }    
    public int getTemps() {
        return temps;
    }
    /*MÈTODES PRIVADOS*/
    private void incrementa() {
        volta++;
        setLliure(volta % durada == 0);
    }

    private void setLliure(boolean lliure) {
        if(this.lliure!=lliure){
            this.lliure = lliure;
            mostraNouEstat(lliure);
            if(lliure){
                temps += (System.currentTimeMillis()-auxTempsIni)/1000;
            }else{
                auxTempsIni=System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
    }
    private void mostraNouEstat(boolean nouEstat){
        cal= new GregorianCalendar();
        if (nouEstat) {
            System.out.println(nom + " acaba de treballar a: " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                    + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        } else {
            System.out.println(nom + " es posa a treballar a: " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                 + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));         
        }
   }
}
```

Hasta aquí todo bien! Pero tengo que implementar 2 clases y no sé por donde comenzar...

La primera se llama `Encarregat`: Este cada vez que se le pide mira si hay trabajadores sin trabajar ( método `isLliure`) i si es así los pone a trabajar. Esta clase tiene `Empresa` como parámetro del constructor..

Tengo esto por ahora:

```
public class Encarregat {

    Empresa e;

    public Encarregat(Empresa e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
}
```

Pero no acabo de ver como hacer las llamadas y lo siguiente es

La clase `GestionTrabajadores`: Lo que tiene que hacer es que ponga a trabajar a todos los trabajadores que esten libres. Se ejecturá cada segundo comienza inmediatamente y espera 60 segundos. Usara tantos procesadores como disponga. Al finalizar hay que llamar al método mostrarTemps.  El tema es que tengo parte hecho pero no sé 100% donde tengo que llamar.

Tengo esto por ahora:

```
public class GestioTreballadors {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // ScheduleExecutor lo que hará es:
        // 1- Hara servir tantos hilos como nombre de procesadores disponga 
        final ScheduledExecutorService schExService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        // EN ESTO TENGO EL PROBLEMA..... //
        final Runnable ob = new GestioTreballadors.new 
Treballador.isLliure();  /// NO SE 100% que poner aquí T_T
        // 2- Lo ejecutara inmediatamente y cada segundo y esperara a finalizar 60 segundos.
        schExService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(ob, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        schExService.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // ShutDown
        schExService.shutdown();
        System.out.println("completado");
        // No se para que usar esto.. :S
        Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
        empresa.mostrarTemps();
    }
}
```

Comment: Si entiendo bien la idea, tienes una `Empresa` que posee `Treballador`es que pueden estar trabajando o no (si no trabajan, están disponibles). Además, tienes una clase `Encarregat` que debe poner a trabajar a los `Treballador`es de una `Empresa` mediante la clase `GestioTreballadors`, debe verificar que su trabajo se complete en 60 segundos o menos. Y si el trabajador vuelve a estar inactivo, que lo haga trabajar nuevamente. ¿Esto es correcto?

Comment: Si :) así es...